# Do PDFs have to be square or rectangular?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, shapes

I'm creating a sticker in Illustrator and was wondering whether when exporting to PDF format, can it only be saved in a rectangular/square shape?

I'm asking because if not then I'd prefer to have a PDF that wraps around the corners and curves to create a more interestingly shaped sticker.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Your question is a bit unclear: the aim of the PDF is to be printed? Usually printers and plotters manage rectangular sheets, and professional printers are able to create irregular cuts for the stickers.

Comment: The image is printed on a square media and then cut into shape yes. No there are no 2d image formats that are non square. (there is a 3d one tough). You can use transparency but most ussers woul not know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

As I originally find it [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8839/14923) acrobat shows a white background by default. You can open the pdf file in Acrobat App and click `Ctrl+K` and check the `Show Transparency Grid`

But by default, browsers and Acrobat app on other PCs will show a white background.

[image]

Comment: That's great, thank Paolo, yes, sorry if my question was a little unclear that what I meant. I'll send to the printers in a rectangular format. Also handy to know about transparency trick Ferdi and Joojaa. that answers my question, help much appreciated