# Save a PDF with a transparent background?

Tags: print-design, pdf, transparency

I have an Illustrator file that I have saved in various formats, including a .PNG. Only my client on a PC, needs it to be a .PDF with a transparent background. This is for print purposes. 
Any suggestions? I've asked google in 100 ways, and still no satisfactory answer!

Thanks!

Comment: It appears this was answered already here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/save-illustrator-as-pdf-with-transparent-background

Essentially, if you have no background in your AI document, there is no background in your PDF it just previews that way.

Answer (score 0):

> Only my client on a PC, needs it to be a .PDF with a transparent background

Your client does NOT need a transparent background for print. If you have a big white background that will remain without ink.

If you need to print for example a dark T shirt where you need an aditional white ink as a background of a silouete, send a separate file of that silouete with the instruction that that is the white background.

If you want to open the pdf in a vector based program, the shapes will reman as you have them, so if the file itself does not have a background you can edit it normally.