# Looking for a way to create a White logo on translucent background that will be viewable in preview?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, transparency, white

I'm delivering a package of logos (saved as .pdf), some of which are white on transparent background. When opened in preview or finder, the files appear blank because those applications default to white backgrounds.. white on white being invisible.

I've explained to the client that the info is there and also provided them with a proofsheet so they can see it in context, but they are still pushing for this issue to be solved.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you ask what the issue is specifically? Is the issue being they're unable to use the logo? Are they unable to find the logo when searching because the logo doesn't show up on the page (white on white)? I would ask them how they want the logo to be seen. This is a software issue with the program they're using to view the PDF's and not the file itself. Check out this similar question - [Save Illustrator as PDF with transparent background](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/save-illustrator-as-pdf-with-transparent-background)

Answer (score 1):

Some clients just ask for nonsenses.

Check if "the client" is only the owner or it has a graphic design departament. If it has, send the file to someone who actually knows what to do with it.

If you are sending an Ilustrator or CorelDraw file, just send a layered document, deactivating the black based layer.

For a png file there is nothing you can do.

But if your client needs the logo inside a Power Point file for example, send him a Power Point file with the logo already inside.